# Can static member fuctions have side effects?

Tags: c++, static

I'm trying to understand how static member functions work in C++.

Below I have created a struct which represents a node-like data type. It has a single method to concatenate two objects.

```
struct obj {
    obj *parent;
    int id;

    obj(int id) {
        this->id = id;
        parent = this;
    }

    static void link(obj parent, obj child) {
        child.parent = &parent;
    }
};
```

And here is the test I've written

```
int main() {
    obj a = obj(1);
    obj b = obj(2);

    obj::link(a, b);

    std::cout << "parent of a = " << a.parent->id << std::endl;
    std::cout << "parent of b = " << b.parent->id << std::endl;

    a.parent = &b;

    std::cout << "parent of a = " << a.parent->id << std::endl;
    std::cout << "parent of b = " << b.parent->id << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

My expectation here would be to have both sets of prints to output the same things, or in
other words, I would expect `a.parent = &b;` to not have any effect on the computation, as calling the function `link` should already have performed this operation.

Unfortunately, running the code does not yield such results, as you can see below.

```
parent of a = 1
parent of b = 2
parent of a = 2
parent of b = 2
```

I suspect this is due to the function being static. Indeed, using the function below yields the desidered output.

```
void linkTo(obj parent) {
    this->parent = &parent;
}
```

I now would like to understand why the first function does not work the way I think it would. I am pretty sure that the equivalent of such function would work in Java, which is a language I am more familiar with.

My understanding is that if member functions are static, they cannot refer to fields of an object, as there is no way to identify which object they should be related to. In this case, however, the objects are being passed as parameters in the function call, so I would expect their members to be accessible and modifiable.

Is there a way to perform the operation presented above using a static member function. If not, why is that the case?

Comment: Are you aware that, in C++, function parameters get passed by value, by default? Do you know what this means? This has nothing to do, whatsoever, with `static` functions. VTC as a typo.

Comment: I've clarified that this involves member functions. Free functions can also be `static`, but that means something entirely different. (linkage)

Comment: A static member function, like any other function, most definitely can refer to fields of **an** object if **an** object is available to it through a parameter, as a global, or in any other way.

Answer (score 2):

`child.parent = &parent;` here `&parent` is a pointer that is only valid inside the function. Once the function returns it is a dangling pointer. If you would dereference that pointer later after the function returned it would cause undefined behavior. Though, also `child` is passed by value, so any changes made to `child` are only made on the object local to the function, which is gone once the function returns.

This has nothing to do with the function being static. It would have the same problem if it was a non-static member function or a free function. The issue is that it takes the parameter by value when you want references:

```
static void link(obj& parent, obj& child) {
    child.parent = &parent;
}
```

Comment: The member function that appears to work also has the same error, but worse: Instead of having fun with two local copies that are soon to be gone, it actually points the member at a local copy that then is destroyed. This creates a dangling pointer that you can actually access.

Comment: @Frodyne oh right. Actually I first misread the question and then fixed the answer only incompletely. Perhaps this question is better served by being refered to some  pass by value vs pass by referene Q&A

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with passing by value (the default means by which C++ passes parameters when not explicitly told to do so otherwise). When you write...

```cpp
static void link(obj parent, obj child) {
  child.parent = &parent;
}
```

...and you call `obj::link(a, b)`, what you're saying is, essentially, "Pass a copy of `a` and a copy of `b` to the `link` function." So `link` now has its copies, does indeed set the copy of `b`'s `parent` member to point at the copy of `a`, and then it returns, and your copies immediately go out of scope and are (or at least can be thought of as) trashed, and your original `a` and `b` remain unaltered.

As has already been pointed out, it has nothing to do with the function being `static`. You could write...

```cpp
static void link(obj& parent, obj& child) {
  child.parent = &parent;
}
```

...and then call `obj::link(a, b)` to explicitly pass *references* to your original `a` and `b`, and the function should then work as you expect.